# how to save and write data on android directory storage/emulated/0/Android/data with python

Tags: python, android, operating-system, kivy, buildozer

i would like to know if it is possible with python os module
Also is it possible to use python-docx on android buildozer kivy apk?

Comment: `if it is possible` ? What would be 'it'?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#storage-paths).

Answer (score 0):

## yes it is possible

you need to add **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**
in buildozer.spec file at android.permission

in python code or in your main.py

you can do this

```
from os.path import join

 def on_pause(self):
   fn = join(self.user_data_dir)
   with open('state.json', 'w') as fd:
   json.dump(self.yourstate, fd)
```

or add that to any function

this may work just fine for you